# How to instantiate scala.scalajs.js.ThisFunction3 in this example using org.singlespaced.d3js' data function

Tags: javascript, scala, d3.js, scala.js

I have a little problem instantiating a `scala.scalajs.js.ThisFunction3` in the following example (using `org.singlespaced.d3js`)

```scala
val selection = myG.selectAll(".res")
   .data[Resource]((r: Container, i: Int) => r.resources.toJSArray, 
      {(n: Node, r: Option[Resource], i:Int) => ""}  // (*) this results in a type mismatch
         : ThisFunction2[Node|js.Array[Resource],js.UndefOr[Resource], Int, String])
```

myG is a `Selection[Container]` and `Container` has a `List[Resource]` field.

I tried to substitute the line marked with (*) with the following code:

```scala
 {(n: js.Array[Resource], r: js.UndefOr[Resource], i:Int) => ""}

 {(n: List[Resource], r: Option[Resource], i:Int) => ""}
```

So far everything I tried resulted in a type mismatch error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**

Here is how the data functions are defined:

```scala
  def data(): js.Array[Datum] = js.native
  def data[NewDatum](data: js.Array[NewDatum]): Update[NewDatum] = js.native
  def data[NewDatum](data: js.Array[NewDatum], key: js.ThisFunction2[dom.Node|js.Array[NewDatum],js.UndefOr[NewDatum], Int, String]): Update[NewDatum] = js.native
  def data[NewDatum <: Datum](data: js.Array[NewDatum], key: js.Function2[Datum, Int, String]): Update[NewDatum] = js.native
  def data[NewDatum](data: DatumFunction[js.Array[NewDatum]]): Update[NewDatum] = js.native
  def data[NewDatum](data: DatumFunction[js.Array[NewDatum]], key: js.ThisFunction2[dom.Node|js.Array[NewDatum],js.UndefOr[NewDatum], Int, String]): Update[NewDatum] = js.native
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `js.ThisFunction2` that you want to obtain has the type `Node|js.Array[Resource]` for the receiver type. Therefore, you arrow function needs to accept an argument of that specific type (or a *supertype*, because argument types are contravariant):

```scala
{(n: Node|js.Array[Resource], r: js.UndefOr[Resource], i:Int) => ""}
```

will compile.

Of course, it means the body of your function must handle `Node`s and `js.Array[Resource]` alike. That is what the function type says, so it is expected: the caller of that function can call it with either a `Node` or a `js.Array[Resource]`, so your function must be able to handle both.

Comment: Works perfectly. I feel a bit stupid for not noticing that myself... thank you very much. :)